# iOS: Keeping a View constant or passing a view between various ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I've got a custom library([devinross/tapkulibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/)) which implements segmented controls. This segmented control is placed within a subview of main view. Now when I change the control on segmented controls then I change to new viewcontroller and redraw the segmented controls at exactly same place. But this is causing me some problems during animations in some cases.

Is it possible that I can assign the segmented control property of new view controller to current property and thereby using the same segmented over various view controllers.

```
// First.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *segmentedView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TKMultiSwitch *multiswitch;
// First.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //multiSwitch initializations
    [self.multiswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.segmentedView addSubview:self.multiswitch];
}

-(void) changedSegmentedControl:(id)sender {
    switch(sender.indexOfSelectedItem)
    {
    case 1:
        Second *controller = (Second*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondvc"];
        controller.multiswitch = self.multiswitch;
        break;
    }
}

// Second.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *segmentedView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TKMultiSwitch *multiswitch;
// Second.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.multiswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.segmentedView addSubview:self.multiswitch];
}
-(void) changedSegmentedControl:(id)sender {
    switch(sender.indexOfSelectedItem)
    {
    case 0:
        First *controller = (First*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstvc"];
        controller.multiswitch = self.multiswitch;
        break;
    }
}
```

For `case 1:` in `switch` section of First.m file, I also tried following but out of luck:

```
[controller.segmentedView addSubView:self.multiSwitch];
```

Also note that I cannot use subviews and show them when segmented controls are changed. I've got to change view controllers.

EDIT : Video showing the what is working and what is not (Here 3 sections are there)

working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lI368z9ntfM

problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTU6tIq5ZW4

Comment: What animation problems are you seeing?

Comment: As I previously kept separate segmented controls I manually selected index in viewDidLoad of Second.h when user touches particular segmented control. But when user drags(or swipes) over segmented control it shows the animation twice as there is same listener event UIControlEventValueChanged.

Comment: So, you have 2 `UISegmentedControl` objects but only 1 listener? Could you make each segmented control have its own listener (i.e., the view controller that displays it)?

Comment: @mbm29414 I do have 2 listener one for each of the view controllers in first.m and second.m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I can't really understand some parts of how and why you want to do what you want to do. 
From what I understood, you want to hide the '**First**' controller and show the '**Second**' controller instead, but in doing so, you don't want to release the '**multiswitch**' control. I also assume you want to completely throw away '**First**' and recreate it if necessary.

To be truthful, I don't really like your solution, but I also don't know a lot about what you are trying to do, so I will just try to give an answer based on the asumptions above.

Add the following lines before creating the **Second** controller, in **changedSegmentedControl:**.

```html
// Remove 'self' as target. You don't want to receive signals in 'First' anymore, because once it will get released you will end up with a crash.
   [self.multiswitch removeTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// Remove the segmented control from it's superview. It will be added in the 'Second' controller view hierarchy.
   [self.multiswitch removeFromSuperview];
```

You are now set. You must also not forget to add '**Second**' as target for the '**multiswitch**' control.
In '**Second.m**', method '**viewDidLoad**', add :

```html
[self.multiswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Of course, you must implement '**changedSegmentedControl:**' in '**Second**' as well.

You would be better off in reusing '**First**' instead of '**Second**' (Initiate a '**First**' controller instead of '**Second**' so that you already have the functionality for the 'multiswitch' control). If you need extra functionality, change '**Second**' in order to inherit '**First**' and add the extra code you need.

Comment: Thanks removing target and adding target again helped.